# What is the normal cone of the constraints of a quadratically constrained quadratic programming(QCQP)?

Tags: optimization, semidefinite-programming, convex-cone, qcqp

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & f_0(x)\\ \text{subject to} & f_i(x) \leq 0\end{array}$$

where

$$f_i (x) := (A_ix+b_i)^T(A_ix+b_i)-c_i^Tx-d_i$$

How can I calculate the normal cone of its constraints?

Comment: You should add your attempt in order to get answers

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used this before, my question is to compute the normal cone of the feasible set of this QCQP. I know that for points in the interior of a set, the normal cone is empty, but how to compute those on the boundary?